# JPG w white background instead of PNG with transparent

Tags: canvas, transparency, gif, jpeg, graphical-logo

Why do I see many websites, both big and small, using `JPG` logos that were created on a solid white canvas instead of a `GIF` or `PNG` with a transparent canvas? It bothers me to see a round logo in the center of a white square as the image placed in a `div` with a gradient (or non-white color) background.

Is there some reason that I dont know about that makes the ugliness of a `JPG` in a white square better than a logo that can be dropped on any color background or are these websites just not doing it proper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is subjective, but I've found a lot of folks implementing websites (both designers and developers) are unfamiliar with the differences between JPGs and PNGs. They're used to everything being a JPG, so they put everything in that format.

When this happens, I try to explain the pros and cons of each format:

- JPGs are great when you have continuous-color photos
- PNGs and GIFs are great when you want transparency: when you want something to merge into the background. GIFs only have "transparent or not", PNGs can have varying levels of transparency (like a drop shadow)
- PNGs and GIFs are great when you have a limited number of colors, like a diagram or most logos, and they can be smaller than a JPG
- PNGs and GIFs are great for things with hard transitions, like text. JPG will give compression artifacts.

I really think it all boils down to education.

Answer (score 0):

It really comes down to filesize. You normally use whatever type of image that gives the smallest file size without compromising the look of the original image.

The size of the image, the number of colors used, the level of details (like gradients and shadows) all affect which format is best for the circumstance. I agree, logos should generally be PNGs and simple. Complex images are usually smallest as JPGs where simple images with few colors are best saved as PNGs.